# Laravel 5.4 Authorization - using can method unsuccessfully

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using **Laravel 5.4** Policies to manage users abilities.

The goal is to delete a post using the **'can' method.**
Even though the destroy method ('DELETE') has been run, it does not successfully go through the if statement to the delete the post.
I have changed the return value in PostPolicy.php to 'true' to remove any other variables into the mix.

PostPolicy.php:

```
public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return true;
}
```

PostsController.php:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    if ($user->can('delete', $post)) {          
        $post->delete();
    }

    return response()->json($post);

}
```

Comment: if it even got to the `if` statement there would be an undefined variable issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting a user instance. If you want to check permissions for authenticated user, use `auth()->user()` object:

```
if (auth()->user()->can('delete', $post)) {          
    $post->delete();
}
```

Or use [`authorize()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-controller-helpers) method:

```
$this->authorize('delete', $post);
$post->delete();
```

> In addition to helpful methods provided to the `User` model, Laravel provides a helpful `authorize` method to any of your controllers which extend the  `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` base class. Like the can method, this method accepts the name of the action you wish to authorize and the relevant model. If the action is not authorized, the `authorize` method will throw an `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException`, which the default Laravel exception handler will convert to an HTTP response with a `403` status code

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-controller-helpers

Comment: I tired both recommend methods. However, I am getting the same result as before and for the second method I get the "Forbidden 403" response.

Comment: @Roo and if you put `dd($post);` right after the query, what does it show? Also, have you [registered the policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#registering-policies)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my AuthServiceProvider.php file.
I did not include the following classes:

```
use App\Post;
use App\Policies\PostPolicy;
```